# Is there any way to change the Product name in the Click once app without changing the version number

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, build, clickonce

I have a click once app which has been published with version number 0.5.2.1 with a product name. I want to change my Product name such that I do not want to increment my version number. All the new users who install my application with version 0.5.2.1 should be able to see the new product name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rename product tag from your **App.application** file
   [image: Product tag]
2. You need for resign your **App.application** file by certificate from your Visual Studio. Please use this file:

[image: Certificate]

3. For sign you can use Mage.exe (from Windows SDKs). Command line options (/?), sign example below:

> mage -Sign **App.application** -CertFile mycert.pfx -Password passwd

Comment: Do i need to publish the build (with the same version number) once doing the changes ?

Comment: :Where can I find the App.application file ?

Comment: It's in your **Publishing Folder** on your screen

Comment: I see that it's an executable file with .Application extension. How do i open that ?